# FireBase - Search String property on "Contains" - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

How can i search `Firebase` for properties that contain a string?

e.g  user post's have descriptions that might say

> "a red t-shirt" "a blue belt" "a silver belt buckle"

How could I search each post for text that says "`belt`" to find everything that has been posted about belts.

It seems `Firebase` only has `.equalTo(String)` and not `.contains(String)`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Firebase indeed supports `equalTo()` and `startAt()`/`endAt()` (with the combination of these you can build a "starts with" like operation). It does not support contains operations.

Comment: Thanks Frank!  I understand why it has to be done the way described in your answer, i was just hoping there was a simpler way.  Hopefully there will be a simpler way with the Firebase API in the future (although i'm guessing there won't be because I can't imagine a contains query being anything but expensive with NOSQL)

Thank you.